# How to find words which contain the first 3 characters input by a user

Tags: python

How can I find words which contain the first 3 characters input by a user. If the file contains words NYL000234 and other words, and user gives an input like NYL, then output would be NYL000234.

Example - Text file contains -

```
10099834 COL01139 OD 1_1_2_1
T1 10115177 COL01356 OD 1_1_3_1
T1 10099848 COL03031 OD 1_1_2_1
T1 10093544 COL03008 OD 1_1_1_1
T1 10101126 COL03050 ID
1_1_2_1 10093697 COL03002 ID
1_1_3_1 10122993 COL05067 ID
1_1_2_1 10093668 COL03047 ID
1_1_2_1 10127012 COL05077 ID
1_1_3_1 10093664 COL03045 ID 1_1_2_1
```

If the user gives input COL then output would be like this..
(output should be column not in row)

```
COL01139
COL01356
COL03031
COL03008
COL03050
COL03002
COL05067
COL03047
COL05077
COL03045
```

Comment: Please try solving this for yourself and providing us with some code to show your attempt! http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: F1=open("SR.txt",'r')
for line in F1:
    line=line.strip().split()
    for word in line: 
        print(word)
choice=("enter the name=")
if (choice==word[:3]):
   print(word)
F1.close()

Comment: F1=open("SR.txt",'r')
for line in F1:
    line=line.strip().split()
    for word in line: 
        print(word)
choice=("enter the name=")
if (choice==word[:3]):
   print(word)
F1.close()

Comment: F1=open("SR.txt",'r')
for line in F1:
    line=line.strip().split()
    print(line)
F1.close()

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
with open("your_file.txt", "r") as file: ## Open file

    lines = file.splitlines() ## Read the lines into a list
    for line in lines: ## Loop through the lines
        for word in line.split(): ## Loop through the words
            if word.lower().startsWith(user_letters.lower()): 
                ## If the word starts with the letters provided by the user
                print(word)
```

Comment: You could make this more pythonic with a list comprehension, try: `[word for line in file.readlines() for word in line.split() if word[:3].lower() == user_letters.lower() ]`

Comment: Also, instead of `word[:3].lower() == user_letters.lower()`, you can simply use `word.lower().startswith(user_letters.lower()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex:

```
import re
results = re.findall('{}\d+'.format(input('enter root: ').upper()), open('filename.txt').read())
```

Output (when input is `"col"`):

```
['COL01139', 'COL01356', 'COL03031', 'COL03008', 'COL03050', 'COL03002', 'COL05067', 'COL03047', 'COL05077', 'COL03045']
```

Comment: @AlokGupta `(input('enter root: ')` returns what entered by the user via the command prompt.